# Multiple databases in Crystal reports

Tags: postgresql, crystal-reports

I have 10 Postgres Databases linked via ODBC which I use in Crystal Reports.
These 10 databases are all the same, same schema and tables.

The 10 databases I need to query from all at the same time, to have one consolidated report. Is this possible? If so, how can i Link the databases to have consolidated data?

I will be using a SQL query to draw the data.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes it is possible you need to use sub reports...one sub report for one database. but if you access 10 databases then performance can degrade...

Comment: Thank you,  I will look into that. Performance won't be an issue as it will only be an once-off report to consolidate data. Will provide feedback when I managed to get it up and running as per your suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right way will be to handle the datasource outside Crystal reports. I am not familiar with Postgres , and I don't know if you can link tables or databases. In SQL server you can use linked servers, in MS Access linked tables, there should be a similar concept in Postgres. The idea is to link an object outside the databse and use it inside the database. This will allow you to prepare a query like this:

select A,B,C FROM server1.database1.table1
UNION
select A,B,C FROM server2.database1.table1
UNION
select A,B,C FROM server3.database1.table1
...
UNION
select A,B,C FROM server10.database1.table1

This query ( or view) will contain all the information and you can base you Crystal report on it. Crystal will work with just one database , the one which contains the query, and the query will deal with the other databases to collect the data. This will be way faster compared to the method when you add your connections to all 10 database directly to Crystal reports.

I don't think subreports are an option here . Each subreport will connect to a separate database and you will get 10 separate subreports. You may get all the data but it will be sorted for each subreport, so you will have A->Z for the first databse then A->Z for the second and so on. Ther will be 10 separate sets of data , which will be presented together but will still behave like separate recordsets.

If Postgres does not support linked databases you can use an Access database as a proxy , just link your tables and use it as a place , which will combine the data

Comment: Good solution indeed +1 for this.... But clarify me one thing here, If you create one query for all 10 databases then how would that query handle the database logins and also what will be the query retrive time.

Comment: Login will be handled by the link. When you are adding linked server or linked table you need to provide connection information and it will be saved inside the proxy database. Retrieve time will be in worst case scenario the same as when Crystal is retrieving the data. Usually it will be way better because the data will be processed by a database engine instead of by Crystal .

Comment: I linked the databases in access, however, because of the same table names, the duplicates all have a number at the end of the table. How can I link all 100 tables to their twin so it can be seen as 100 tables and not 1000 tables? ( 100 tables x 10 databases )

Comment: You cannot link 2 tables as one. You will have 2 tables and the name really doesn't matter because you are going to write a query like this select A,B,C from table1 union select A,B,C from table2 union ... select A,B,C from table100. This query will return the data from all 100 tables and you can filter it in a single SQL